# Do mines pay out at the end of the last phase in Castles of Burgundy?

Tags: the-castles-of-burgundy

For Mines, the rules state:

> ...at the end of *each* phase, the player recieves 1 Silverling from the supply for each mine in his estate.

And in the Game End section:

> The game ends after the fifth phase has been played through to completion.

My reading of these rules are that after the final round of phase E players would receive 1 Silverling for each mine they have and then the final scores would be counted.  So effectively you'd get an extra point for each mine you have at the end of the game.

Is this correct, incorrect or something ambiguous where you could just agree on the interpretation before the start of the game.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your reading is right - you do get 1 Silverling (effectively 1 point) per mine at the end of phase E. If you want evidence beyond the rules you quoted, check out the reminder icon on the board that says "A-E":

[image: Icon from the game board showing a mine; below it is a Silvering, a slash, and then the text "A-E"]

Comment: We just got this game and this is the question we had as we ended.   As I understand it, you pay out the mines at the end of phase e and those silverlings are worth 1 VP each.  Did we get that right? We were not sure if we'd gotten that right.

Comment: Yes, mines still produce a silverling at end of E and then that becomes a VP in final scoring.